# Org Wide defaults

Tags: permissions

I have renamed a user in my Org. Due to this all the opportunities which belonged to the previous user is showing against for the user I have updated with a new name.

Our OWD setting on Optys is private.

Now how can I restrict the new user to not to access the old users opptys.

Comment: Not that is helps now, but this is a GREAT lesson for everyone on why you do not want to just change a user to a new user. Edit the user and uncheck "Active" then create a new user. You preserve historical information and the new user will have the appropriate visibility. Inactive users do not count against your user license count. if you can change the user back to the original, deactivate them, and create a new user.

Comment: @Eric  why not put this as the answer?  It's really worth more than a little comment :)

Comment: @NickCook - Ok. Please feel free to add to it as there is much more to it than what I put which is why I originally made it a comment.

Answer (score 5):

Not that is helps now, but this is a **GREAT lesson** for everyone on why you **do not** want to just change a user to a new user.

**To properly add a new user in place of another:**

1. Edit the user and uncheck "Active"
2. Create a brand new user for the new person.

**There are many reasons for doing so but the simplest ones are:**

1. You preserve historical information for the old user, what they owned, did, etc
2. Security around the records of the old user remain intact
3. The new user will have the appropriate visibility and not have old user records mixed in with theirs.

**Regarding License Count:**

Inactive users do not count against your user license count.

**How to resolve**

1. Change the user back to the original
2. Deactivate the user
3. Create a completely new user record for the new user